# How to keep track of downloads using python or any other language?

Tags: java, python, browser, scripting, download

Well this is just something i am wondering if it is possible.
I have a router and n number of people are connected to it. Now i want to track the downloads , like which person [computer] downloaded what and how much [the size] and finally store the information somewhere in a file / database.
Is this possible? Please don't recommend software, i want to write a code that will run continuously and keep checking for downloads. Downloads should include even the surfing, like when you open facebook some data is downloaded, even that should be added.
If not possible for router is it possible for individual computer?
It would be really useful if it works for a router situation.
Thanks for your help in advance.